# Load image... when time is eating up

Tags: javascript, image

here is a sameple code, I would like to know when the browser is REALLY loading image

when you assign an image path to a array like that

```
imageNames[0] = 'image1.jpg';
```

or when you make

```
myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = imageNames[0];
```

i have put some timer.. but did not get concluant result ! HELP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would look at the `load` event. Attach it with the ancient `onload` or `addEventListener()`/`attachEvent()` depending on your browser support requirements.

```
myImage = new Image;

myImage.onload = function() {
   alert('Image loaded');
}

myImage.src = imageNames[0];
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LuJec/).

You could also check if the image is already loaded by checking the `complete` property.

Answer (score 2):

The key thing to note is that just because a human being can see that something *could be* a resource identifier / locator, the computer cannot.

When you assign a string to a point in an array:

```
imageNames[0] = 'image1.jpg';
```

the fact that `'image1.jpg'` is a licit path to an image on your.host.net is not something the browser can determine on its own - the browser **cannot** recognize that the string `'image1.jpg'` is a resource representation rather than a resource itself.

Once you set a DOM image's `src` property to be the string `'image1.jpg'` the browser *can* recognize the string should be treated as a resource identifier (because the DOM element you created is an image, and the image's `src` property is supposed to be a URI pointing at an image resource which can be accessed and downloaded) and the browser will try and acquire that resource through means of its own.

Answer (score 2):

The browser downloads the image when you assign a URL to the `src` attribute of an `img` element. Try this in the console of your browser and watch the Network tab:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'foo';
```

You'll see network activity as soon as that second line executes.

It most certainly does nothing for `imageNames[0] = 'image1.jpg';` since a string in an array could be anything, there's no way the browser has any idea this is supposed to be the URL of an image.